# Fingerprint scanner in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to make a fingerprint scanner in minecraft that lets players through a door. I want this to be realistic, so that the player actually has do to something with their hand in order to be let in. I don’t want to stray too far from the point, but this is (in a nutshell) how it works:

1. The player rotates glass in an item frame.
2. A command block system detects whether the player should
    be allowed in and, supposing the player is allowed in;
3. The glass in the item frame turns green.

I have got part 2, but I need help with part one and three, so, in conclusion:

1. How do I use `/testfor` to detect glass rotating in an item
    frame and;
2. How do I `/setblock` `green_stained_glass_pane`?

Comment: "How do I use /testfor to…" Answer: You don't. This is not 1.7, you don't need testfor for everything. You don't need it for anything anymore. And I'm pretty sure you're also using a comparator for that, you also don't need to do that. You don't need any redstone.

Comment: This is the wiki page that answers your NBT questions: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Chunk_format#Other
And for checking and changing NBT, you can use `/execute` or `/data`, both also have wiki pages.

Comment: Ok @FabianRöling so if I don’t need /testfor for part one, do I use /execute or /data?

Comment: Also I looked at the wiki link and I couldn’t make anything of it.

Comment: Also In your comment, @FabianRöling, you said ‘Answer’. If you are answering my question, I would really appreciate it if you would take the time to write your answer as an answer, and explain it in a more digestible way as both these commands are fairly new to me. Thanks.

Comment: No, because it's not a full answer to your main question. I just pointed out that `testfor` shows a wrong approach to commands. I thought it was even removed in 1.13, but apparently not. I can't give you a guide how to replace `testfor` in all instances, because it depends on what you want to do. You're thinking of it as "if there's a thing, activate redstone", but it should be "if there's a thing, do something". I would recommend you to watch/read a commands tutorial that is at most as old as 1.9, preferably newer, best 1.13.

Comment: The "chunk format" page tells you the exact NBT path for the item in an item frame and to understand it, look up an example `data merge` command. The rotation is just another NBT tag that you can base your other comnand (step 2) on with `execute if` or `execute store` or `execute as` or whatever, depending on your step 2. NBT target selectors might help you, they might not be useful, I don't know.

Comment: @FabianRöling How would you replace /testfor if you just wanted to use /setblock

Comment: `execute as/at/if/unless/… <condition> run setblock <arguments>`. I guess the closest to `testfor` is `execute if entity`, which only executes the chained command if the tested for entity exists. But `execute` allows for so many more things, you should look for a commands tutorial like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KPcwQkNanus&index=2&list=PLoRB7paAOwAdKJxEa7NkdVtnSPhoKlT47) or some example commands.

Comment: Archive link for my comment from 5.8.2018 18:38: https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/index.php?title=Chunk_format&oldid=1257079#Other

Answer (score 2):

For 1, you can either use a `/data get entity @e[type=item_frame,limit=1] ItemRotation`  or a comparator.

For 3, you can simply just use `/kill @e [type=item_frame,limit=1]` and then `/summon ItemFrame <x> <y> <z> {Direction:facingb,Item:{green_stained_glass_pane}}`  replacing "facing" (leave the letter b as it is) with the way it is facing (0=south, 1=west, 2=north, and 3=east.)

Also, item frames count as entities, not as blocks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put a comparator behind the item frame
2. use a command block to find the redstone level of the comparator or just a regular old password switch will do
3. Then a simple player testfor command will take it from there

Comment: Ok, the first part is helpful @Devan S. but please could you expand on the /testfor command and using /setblock command to /setblock stained glass into an item frame?

Comment: just say /execute @p[name=username] ~ ~ ~ setblock (abs coors)

Comment: if you want to be fancy, then /execute @e[type=item_frame,c=1] ~ ~ ~ execute @p[name=username] ~ ~ ~ setblock x y z...

Comment: How do you find a player with /execute as testfor was removed?

Comment: ,how do you /setblock stained_glass_pane into an item frame?

Comment: try running /data get entity @e[type=item_frame,limit=1] and look around for something that may help you

Comment: I want to do this in 1.13

Comment: replace /execute @p[]... with /execute at @p[]... and then setblock... with run setblock...

Comment: Why would you check the comparator level instead of the item frame itself? That just introduces a needless delay and restricts your building options, for example the item frame can't hang on a pillar or wall between two rooms anymore.

Comment: because it's simpler

Answer (score 0):

With command blocks you can use this setup:

1. First, use a repeating command block that's always active with the command:

```
/testfor @a <coordinates of block in front of your "scanner".
```

You can then have a comparator run out of it and into the second command block.

2. Then a repeating command block which needs redstone:

```
/testforblock <position of wool block>
```

Then have a comparator running out of two redstone dust one piece to the left of the first piece and one to the right of the first piece.

3. Last, place a command block at each end of the redstone dust the one two the left which should say:

```
/setblock <coordinates of were the wool should be> wool <data value of the color you want>
```

The right one should say:

```
/setblock <coordinates of the left of the wool> concrete <data value of lime>
```

and the front one should say

```
/setblock <the block under the block under the door> redstone_block
```

Out of the front and right block should be a comparator 2 repeaters set to four tick and another repeater set to 2 ticks for a 1 second delay attached to both of those should be a command_block. The right one should say:

```
/setblock <where the lime concrete is> concrete <data value for red>
```

The front one should say:

```
/setblock <the block under the block under the door air.
```

Comment: I find your comment confusing and I’m not sure it answers my question

Comment: This answer is confusing, as it is a huge run on sentence. It also doesnt use the correct format for the commands mentioned.